# Cannont Find Symbol Error, Incompatible Types

Tags: java

Hello I am attempting to write a program that calculates a future investment value using a fixed rate and I am having issues with my variables.  Any help would be much appreciated thank-you ahead of time!

```
  /**
  * NAME:
  * DATE: November 3, 2015
  * FILE: 
  * COMMENTS: This program caculates a future investment value using a fixed rate
  */
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab12
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   //declare variables
   double yearlyInterstRate;
   double monthlyInterestRate;
   double monthlyInvestmentAmount;
   double years;
   double months;

   //Create Scanner Object
   Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

   //Get Investment Information
   System.out.print("Hello we will be caculating the future of your fixed monthly investment, I will need to collect some information from you.");
   System.out.print("What is your monthly investment amount?");
   monthlyInvestmentRate=keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.print("How many years wil you be investing for?");
   years=keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.print("What is your yearly interest rate?");
   yearlyInterestRate=keyboard.nextLine();
   //Caculate the future rate
   {
      months=years*12;
      monthlyInterestRate=yearlyInterestRate/12/100;
      futureValue= CaculateFuturevalue(monthlyInvestedAmount,monthlyInterestRate,months);
      System.out.print("Your future value is $"+futureValue);
    }
 } //Close Main
} //close lab12
```

Comment: And the error is...? *Always* give complete details of the error - the exact error message, and where it's occurring.

Comment: *"having issues with variables"*. Please be more specific. Read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Also, take a look here, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: `yearlyInterstRate` is misspelled. `monthlyInvestmentAmount` is not same as `monthlyInvestedAmount` and both are unassigned before use. `futureValue` is undefined. `nextLine()` returns a `String`, but you're assigning to a `double`, so use `nextDouble()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misspelling in variables.

You have declared `yearlyInterstRate` but you're using `yearlyInterestRate`, so you need to use the variables as they were declared.

also you need to use `monthlyInvestmentAmount` not `monthlyInterestRate` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do:

```
public class lab12
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declare variables
        double yearlyInterstRate;
        double monthlyInterestRate;
        double monthlyInvestmentAmount=0; // you forgot to initialize this value
        double years;
        double months;
        double futureValue;
        //Create Scanner Object
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get Investment Information
        System.out.print("Hello we will be caculating the future of your fixed monthly investment, I will need to collect some information from you.");
        System.out.print("What is your monthly investment amount?");
        monthlyInterestRate=keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("How many years wil you be investing for?");
        years=keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is your yearly interest rate?");
        yearlyInterstRate=keyboard.nextDouble();
        //Caculate the future rate

            months=years*12;
            monthlyInterestRate=yearlyInterstRate/12/100;
            futureValue= caculateFuturevalue(monthlyInvestmentAmount,monthlyInterestRate,months);
            System.out.print("Your future value is $"+futureValue);

    } 
}
```

Now some improvements:

1. use `nextDouble()` instead of `nextLine()`, bacause your variables are double, not String.
2. name your class from upperCase, so `Lab12`, and not `lab12`
3. argumen validation would be nice (check if given values are grater than zero)